# how to insert variable into SQL query

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, groovy, katalon-studio

i have test scripts, the productId is stored in text file which I can use the read method to retrieve it.

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*
import groovy.json.JsonOutput as JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper as JsonSlurper
import internal.GlobalVariable as GlobalVariable
import internal.GlobalVariable
import com.kms.katalon.core.configuration.RunConfiguration
import java.sql.*
import java.io.File

//Read productId
def productId = new File(RunConfiguration.getProjectDir() + "/Data Files/productId.txt")

//SQL statement
String dbQuery2 = /SELECT * FROM db.table1 where productId= @productId order by lastmodificationdateutc desc/
```

how do i use the @ as variable and replace it with the "productId.text" ?

i have tried below codes but it does not work
please correct me if this method can be used?

```
    String dbQuery2 = "SELECT * FROM db.table1 where productId = ?"
    def productId = new File(RunConfiguration.getProjectDir() + "/Data Files/productId.txt")
    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(dbQuery2)
    stmt.setString(1, productId.text)
    ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()

ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery()

//Connect to PostgresSQL, global variable is stored at profile
List resultSet = CustomKeywords.'test.database.getPostgresSQLResults'(GlobalVariable.dbConnString2 , GlobalVariable.dbUsername2 , GlobalVariable.dbPassword2 ,GlobalVariable.dbDriver2 ,dbQuery2 )
```

below is codes which is working without preparedstatement

the connection string in the script

```
//to connect PostgresSQL server
    @Keyword
    def List getPostgresSQLResults (String dbConnString2 , String dbUsername2 , String dbPassword2 , String dbDriver2 , String dbQuery2){

        Sql sql = Sql.newInstance(dbConnString2,dbUsername2,dbPassword2,dbDriver2)

        List results = sql.rows(dbQuery2)

        return results

        sql.close()
    }
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Huh, `def productId = new File`  - what do you think `productId.text` is?

Comment: @ScaryWombat the"def productId = new File(RunConfiguration.getProjectDir() + "/Data Files/productId.txt")" is the katalon built in to read the file. it works at other script. so i use the productId.text to place as varable.

Comment: or any other method how can i bind the data stored in the text file into query statement?

Comment: What is `preparedStatement`? There is no declaration of this variable?

Comment: What are you using to connect to the database?

Comment: @Andronicus i have another script which store connection string of postgres , it is always working find , previously i input the product id directly. i will edit main post to show how is works before using PreparedStatement for the variable value purpsoe.

Comment: @Andronicus i updated latest codes, now i spotted the 'List resultSet = ' is that conflict with "ResultSet resultSet = " ? but the error is something like groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: con for class  , which i have import java.io.File
import java.sql.*
import java.sql.PreparedStatement

Comment: @Andronicus anyway, i decided NOT to use preparedStatement, i managed to find the right syntax to act as variable, dbQuery2 = /SELECT * FROM db.table1 where productId = '${productId.text}'/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use this syntax to act as variable

```
def productId = new File(RunConfiguration.getProjectDir() + "/Data Files/productId.txt")
dbQuery2 = /SELECT * FROM db.table1 where productId = '$productId.text}'/
```

Comment: Is this the answer @Andronicus provided? If yes, then you should accept his/her answer and not post their answer as your own.

Comment: @MateMrše nope. i found out this myself